# Hibernate- Find employees who are not managers

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

I have a table employee with a column manager which reference employee_id.
It is a one to one relationship as each employee can have one manager and each manager can manage one employee:

```
   public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {
   @OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="manager_id" ,referencedColumnName = "employee_id", nullable=true)
private Employee manager;
```

What I am trying to do is to find employees who are NOT managers. I need to do it using hibernate. 
I know that "Not in" or "Not exists" also works but they are super slow in my case and therefore I am trying to use Left join which is much faster.

When I try to use left join the "ON clause" is wrong .
This is what I get

```
 from
     employees employe0_ 
 left outer join
     employees employe1_ 
       on employe0_.manager_id=employe1_.employee_id
```

However what I expect is

```
      on employe0_.employee_id=employe1_.manager_id
```

Comment: I know that I can't use ON clause in hibernate, I think I am using the correct query. I have the association in my entity and I do a left join on that:

Comment: As I mentioned I am using hibernate and hibernate doesn't allow "ON clause" in join statements. I am tested my code in native SQL using on clause and it works fine.

Comment: Again as I mentioned in the question "Not in" is super slow.

Comment: Can you check this? You can remove the `on` :  https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate-left-join-example.html

Comment: *Hibernate- Find employees who are not managers* to be honest that query suggest more "find employees that are not managers TO THEMSELVES"

Comment: Something like this : SELECT * FROM employees e LEFT JOIN employees m WHERE m.manager = null

Comment: Also I'm wondering if this simple query would work : `select employee_id, manager_id
from employees
where manager_id is null 
or manager_id = employee_id`

Comment: @Antoniossss why is that? I want employees who are not managers. Something with the result of "not  in" but using left join. And also using hibernate. My problem is that hibernate generates incorrect "on clause". I tested the left join in SQL and it worked fine but I get a wrong on clause using hibernate

Comment: But if i am correct manager_id is just id of manager of given employee right? It say nothing about employee beeng a manager. What you want to do is `EXISTS` query. `SELECT .... FROM Employee e WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT e2 From Employee e2 WHERE e2.manager_id=e.id)`

Comment: Yes "Not exists" works but it is very slow. I tested this in native SQL and it was fast:      
 `select * from employee as e  left join 
   (select manager_id from employee  where m.manager_id is not null) as m
   on m.manager_id=e.employee_id 
   where m.manager_id is null `

Comment: And now I am trying to do the same thing in hibernate but it gives me wrong "ON clause" when I see the logs.

Comment: You cant always use native query

Comment: Thanks, I will use native query then.